# Glossaries-extra issue: undefined control sequence error caused by record option

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

there doesn't seem to be a question on this specific topic so here's my problem:
I'm using glossaries-extra to create a list of symbols at the beginning of my thesis but I have a weird error popping out, although the documents is being modified correctly and no other issue seems to appear.

Here's my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

and here's my error:

```
E: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra.sty:11249 Undefined control sequence {}
```

This seems to be caused by the record option (?) which is fundamental for the package to work, so I just can't take it out. Suggestion?

P.s. it seems obvious, but I specify it anyway: it is not caused by the absence of elements to record because it happens in my actual documents where there are some entries.

P.p.s. the weirdest part is that everything else seems to work perfectly: my list of symbols is created with the right characteristics.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example. Your code is not a minimal example because it doesn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: It does on my system... If you can't reproduce it, it might mean that the package is not correctly installed. I'll try to reinstall it. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't... anyway tracking down the error I've found the source of it, this command in glossaries-extra.sty: 
`\@ifpackageloaded{tracklang}
{%
\AnyTrackedLanguages
{%
   \ForEachTrackedDialect{\this@dialect}{\glsxtr@loaddialect}%
 }%
  {}%
}%`

commenting all of this out make everything work perfectly...

Comment: You can add your own answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I came up with so far:
The problem seems to be not reproducible on other people's systems, so it's probably a package related issue, or package conflict. Unfortunately reinstalling everything doesn't solve the issue, I've found a inelegant solution though.

The problem seems to arise in the following piece of code:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{tracklang}
{%
  \AnyTrackedLanguages
  {%
    \ForEachTrackedDialect{\this@dialect}{\glsxtr@loaddialect}%
  }%
  {}%
}%
```

around the line 11245 in glossaries-extra.sty. Commenting out these lines removes any error and make everything working (seemingly) perfectly.